# vector with period (hours of operation) and numbers (with decimals), change to numbers

Tags: r

I have a vector MTBF [chr] in which I have together hours of operation, in format "xxx:xx", and numbers in the format "xxx.xx", that are also hours. I need to change everything to "xxx.xx"

[image]

Comment: 15023:1 should go as 15023.16 (ie 15023 hrs and 10 min would be 15023.16 hrs)

Comment: 16548.00 would remain as 16548.00, 14,821.61 should go as 14821.61, "." as N/A and 0 as 0

Comment: 36/60=0.6, so 17717.6

Comment: Please add data using `dput`, something which we can copy and use to provide an answer. Images are not helpful. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option is to convert the elements having the `:` to `period` class and then with `period_to_seconds` convert it to seconds and divide by 3600.  Then we change the whole column to numeric

```
library(lubridate)
FH$MTBF <- sub(",", "", FH$MTBF)
i1 <- grep(":", FH$MTBF)
FH$MTBF[i1] <- period_to_seconds(hm(FH$MTBF[i1]))/3600
as.numeric(FH$MTBF)
#[1]       NA 15023.02     0.00 18308.47  14812.61 17717.60
```

---

Or another option is `separate` the column into two, then divide the 'Min' column by 60 and convert to `numeric` after adding the 'Hour' and 'Min'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
 FH %>%
    mutate(MTBF = str_remove_all(MTBF, ","))%>%
    separate(MTBF, into = c("Hour", "Min"), sep=":",  remove = FALSE) %>% 
    mutate(Min = as.numeric(str_pad(Min, width = 2, pad = 0, side = 'right'))/60, 
          Hour = as.numeric(Hour)) %>% 
   transmute(Pass, MTBF = coalesce(Hour + Min, as.numeric(MTBF)))
```

-output

```
#  Pass     MTBF
#1    .       NA
#2    D 15023.17
#3    .     0.00
#4    . 18308.47
#5    N 14812.61
#6    N 17717.60
```

#### data

```
FH <- structure(list(Pass = c(".", "D", ".", ".", "N", "N"), MTBF = c(".", 
"15023:1", "0", "18308:28", "14,812.61", "17717:36")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I could change things with gsub and sub, but the vector is >2000 rows and needed to put hour:minute to hour.fraction_of_hour

Comment: @Stack2020 if it is a `.`, then the value remains the same, right?

Comment: Correct, "." remain "." I have sorted out that part, those will change to N/A

Comment: Thanks!! This seems to work!! Thought though there was a shorter way of converting hours to a number with decimals. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace a specific type of string I'd recommend the [`stringr`-package](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/) for that which is also part of the [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/).

```
old_strings <- c("123:4", "432:1", "234:1")

new_strings <- old_strings %>% stringr::str_replace(pattern = ":", replace = ".")
```

If you later want to convert those entries into numbers you could do this using

`new_numbers <- new_strings %>% as.numeric()`

Or did you want to change your data from `hour:minute` to `hour.fraction_of_hour`?

Comment: Thanks!! The problem is that if I replace ":" by "." that is not exactly the same. I mean, 10:45 (10hrs and 45 min) is 10.75 hrs. 10.75 is the number I want to obtain

Comment: I had already done your suggestion with sub(":",".", MTBF)

Comment: correct, I want to change from hour:minute to hour.fraction_of_hour